# java sql update / delete do nothing

Tags: java, sql

IM not sure if this is the place, but im out of ideas, the follow is an update code for my program, its simple, but for some reason is does not work.

```
private void txt_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try{
       String value1= txt_id.getText(); 
       String value2= txt_title.getText();
       String value3= txt_firstname.getText();
       String value4= txt_lastname.getText();

        String sql="update publishers set publisher_id='"value1"', publisher_title='"value2"', publisher_name='"value3"', publisher_lastname='"value4"' WHERE publisher_id='"value1"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);            
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    Update_table();  
}
```

im not sure what goes wrong. I tried changing things around but doesnt help. It works within the program, but it does not actually update the database. so when i restart the program nothing changed

ok i tried the following as well without success.

```
private void txt_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try{
       String value1= txt_id.getText(); 
       String value2= txt_title.getText();
       String value3= txt_firstname.getText();
       String value4= txt_lastname.getText();
         String sql="update publishers set publisher_id='" + value1 + "', publisher_title='" + value2 + "',publisher_name='" + value3 + "', publisher_lastname='" + value4 + "'WHERE publisher_id='" + value1 + "'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.execute();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    Update_table();  
}
```

and this one

```
private void txt_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try{


        String sql="update publishers set publisher_id=?, publisher_title=?, publisher_name=?, publisher_lastname=? WHERE publisher_id=?";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txt_id.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_title.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txt_firstname.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txt_lastname.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txt_id.getText());

        pst.execute();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    Update_table();  
}
```

update_table is the following

```
    private void Update_table(){
        try{
        String sql="select publisher_id, publisher_title, publisher_name, publisher_lastname from publishers";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        Table_Publishers.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

   }
```

Comment: IS there an actual error? As it is, this code shouldn't compile.

Comment: i see your what you mean, i changed something while posting i have it tried like it suggested below, but nothing gives me an error.

Comment: It seems like your build process is off. Are you compiling the right file? Are you then running the right file? What happens if you output a message in this function — do you receive the message or does nothing happen?

Comment: What is this method for `Update_table();`

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block. and instead of using `pst.execute();` try using `pst.executeUpdate();`

Comment: you mean like this
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

Comment: @user1944369: Yes Exactly. If you tried all that and still not getting correct seems very weird. Try to run and find the exception. Also try to debug. I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: for some reason there is no change. i'm not sure what is going on. I thought of rewriting, but that would probably not help.

Comment: would it help if i post the whole script, the same is happening with my delete  button, for now i put that to rest. untill this one is solved.

Comment: try to debug the code. If you are using eclipse  [http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm ](Eclipse Debug Tutorial). Mostly the problem is residing somewhere else.

Comment: im not using eclipse, but ill try to debug it, it gotta be somewhere.

Comment: You have to work fast. I am going home soon. may be try to put your code in pastebin and put the link in your question. I will take a look.

Comment: you can find it for now on
http://territorymanagement.z2development.com/script.txt

Comment: @user1944369 I took a look at your code. Everything looks fine. It seems that `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` is creating problem. Try to remove that and see if it works.

Comment: ok i tried a lot of things and did get a little closer, if i put an id in straight like this update publishers set publisher_name='isthisis' WHERE publisher_id=3 and than do not select an actual record than is will do something

Answer (score 3):

That code looks like it will not compile. Use the parameters of the preparedstatement instead.

```
  String sql="update publishers set publisher_id=?, publisher_title=?, publisher_name=?, publisher_lastname=? WHERE publisher_id=?";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, value1);
    pst.setString(2, value2);
    pst.setString(3, value3);
    pst.setString(4, value4);
    pst.setString(5, value1);
    pst.execute();
```

Comment: Are you sure that the id you are providing exist in the table? Also, remove the set publisher_id = ? from the query as that field does not change, maybe it is an autoincrement field.

Comment: the id is there, and i took field out of querry wothout any result

Answer (score 1):

That code would not compile because you aren't concatenating the strings correctly in the query, it should be:

```
String sql="update publishers set publisher_id='"+value1+"', publisher_title='"+value2+"', publisher_name='"+value3+"', publisher_lastname='"+value4+"' WHERE publisher_id='"+value1+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your program such that you use:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
int updateCount = st.executeUpdate(sql);
if(updateCount <= 0) {
  System.out.println("Nothing update in database");
} else {
  System.out.println("Number of records updated: " + updateCount);
}
st.close();
```

Also make sure that you have not disabled autocommitting.

```
if(!con.getAutoCommit()) {
  con.commit();
}
```